# How to create a map from a group of bindings using their names as keys?

Tags: clojure

I want something like an inverse of `{:keys [...]}` construct:

`(let [x 1 y 2 z 3] (create-map x y z))`

...should return `{:x 1 :y 2 :z 3}`.

In other words, I want to avoid typing name of each variable twice as in `{:x x :y y :z z}`.

An example of what I want this function for:

```
(defn create-some-service-handle [user-id password api-key] 
    { :api-key api-key 
      :user-id user-id 
      :connection (obtain-connection user-id password) })
```

Comment: I don't understand what sort of solution you are looking for. Do you 1) only need a solution for how to make the `create-map` function whose behavior you have outlined? Or 2) do you really want something that would behave like this: `=> (binding-vec-to-hash-map [x 1 y 2 z 3]) => {:x 1 :y 2 :z 3}` ... OR maybe 3) do you want something nested inside a `let` that will return a hash-map equivalent of the current bindings? For example: `=> (let-and-bind-all-to-hash-map [x 1 y 2 z 3 :map-name map-of-all-bindings] (:x map-of-all-bindings)) => 1` ... or perhaps something else entirely?

Comment: No, just (1). A macro that will take binding names and construct a map with those names as keys and corresponding values as values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are looking for something that will be able to stand right in exactly where `create-map` is, then you will need a macro, because you will need to take those symbols unevaluated. It would be a pretty straightforward macro:

```
(defmacro create-map
  [& syms]
  (zipmap (map keyword syms) syms))
```

This simply takes the unevaluated symbols, `map`s `keyword` down them to obtain a sequence of keywords, then `zipmap`s the key sequence with the original symbols. Since it is a macro, after this the resulting form will be evaluated, yielding a mapping of keywords to values (the values the symbols refer to).

So that if you go to do:

```
(let [x 1 y 2 z 3] (create-map x y z))
```

...it will return:

```
{:x 1 :y 2 :z 3}
```

Comment: I think we still have a misunderstanding. `(create-name x y z)` is not a placeholder, it's how I want to call this macro. The whole point is to avoid typing each name twice.

Comment: I think I still do not understand, sorry. Could you give a direct input/expected output example? I am going off your input/output example from above, where you say "`(let [x 1 y 2 z 3] (create-map x y z))`... should return `{:x 1 :y 2 :z 3}`". From what I can see, if you defined the macro as I did at the bottom, then did `(let [x 1 y 2 z 3] (create-map x y z))`, it would return `{:x 1 :y 2 :z 3}`.

Comment: Thank you, that was the exact solution I needed.

Comment: That's very cool. How would I get it to have namespaced keywords instead? (create-map x y z) to return {::x 1 ::y 2 ::z 3}. The namespace being the namespace from which I call the macro of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Fixpoint: While the solution you are seeking will work, it is unclear why you "want to avoid typing name of each variable twice". If that is a "personal preference" then this looks like an abuse of the macro facility because the convenience obtained by using the macro is minimal compared to using {:x 1 :y 2 :z 3} or (hash-map :x x :y x :z x).  You seem to be buying too little convenience in exchange for code complexity.

Macros can make your code less maintainable (others may not understand them), introduce complications like symbol-capture (chances are your code will be doing more than simply hash-map creation) and can't be used/passed-around like higher-order functions (unless you wrap them).

Excerpt from "Joy Of Clojure" (Section 8.8):
"the most important skill that you can learn on your path toward macro mastery is the ability to recognize when to avoid using them. The general answer of course is whenever, and as often as you can."

Comment: See the example I added to the question. I have encountered such pattern in many places: i.e. I compute some values for bindings, use them for a while and then return as a map.

Comment: I don't understand why the convenience of destructuring a map into bindings (using {:keys [x y z]}) is fine and part of the language but the reverse operation is not a good thing.